# Fast algorithm to calculate n! / (q!)^r

Tags: java, algorithm, math, factorial

What is the fastest algorithm and the code implementation to calculate the value of the following expression?

> n! / (q!)<sup>r</sup>

My code

```
public static double timesbyf(int n,int q,int qt,int qp1,int qp1t)
{
    int totaltimes=qt+qp1t;
    double ans=1.0d;
    for(int i=1;i<=totaltimes;i++)
    {
        if(i<=qt)
        {
            for(int j=q;j>0;j--)
            {
                ans=ans*((double)n/(double)j);
                n--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int j=qp1;j>0;j--)
            {
                ans=ans*((double)n/(double)j);
                n--;
            }

        }
    }
    while(n>0)
    {
        ans=(ans*n)%3046201;
        n--;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

That is, `n!` divided by `q!` `r` times.

I'm given that n ≤ 3 × 10<sup>6</sup> and that q < n, and it is guaranteed that (q!)<sup>r</sup> will cleanly divide n!.

Comment: Is (q!)^r guaranteed to cleanly divide n!?

Comment: yes gauranteed to cleanly divide n!

Comment: It's not reasonable to ask for code for this without demonstrating that you've made an effort to code it up yourself.  Otherwise, it looks like you're trying to get us to either (a) do your homework for you, or (b) do a programming contest for you.  Plus, it's not reasonable to post the question, get an answer with no code in it, then change your question to ask for code.

Comment: i dont know how to implement the algorithm below thats why i need code
is there a problem to give the code implementation?

Comment: I don't feel comfortable giving out code for a problem that looks like a homework question, especially given that you have provided no context for where you are planning on using this.  You will need to get someone else to write the code for you, or will need to do it yourself.

Comment: this is a part of question on codeforces

Comment: You are asking me to write code for you for a programming contest - that's really, really dishonest.  Write your own code.

Comment: but your answer is not clear

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31546/discussion-between-vidyut-vyom-and-templatetypedef)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a very bad idea to calculate two very large numbers and hope that the quotient comes out as something sensible.

Start by taking the natural log:

```
ln(n!/(q!)^r) = ln(n!) - r*ln(q!)
```

You can use `gammaln()` for the two function values, simplify, then take `exp()` to get the result you want:

```
value = exp(gammln(n+1) -r*gammln(q+1))
```

[Numerical Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521880688) has a nice chapter on how to implement functions like `gammln().`

Comment: but i dont have to calculat combination.its a different topic

Comment: See my edit.  It's still the right way to be thinking about it.

Comment: Your suggestion of using the gamma function is good, but he isn't computing binomial coefficients.  (And for binomial coefficients, you should be using an implementation of the beta logarithm that's a little more careful than just taking differences of gamma logarithms.)

Comment: but in this we have to compute n! which is very because n<=10^5.

Comment: you aren't getting it.  gamma(n) = (n-1)!, except it's less naive than the typical student implementation.  using ln helps with the size problem.

Comment: so r u telling that first i should calculate lngamma(n)
then r*lngamma(q) and substract it and then use exp to get the ans??
am i right??

Comment: that's what i said.  does that look right to you, know how logarithms work?  looks right to me.  just note that gamma(q+1) = q!.  make sure you substitute the right argument into the function.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have a low upper bound on n, it's possible to start off by factoring all of the numbers in the range [1, 3 × 10<sup>6</sup>].  There are many ways to do this reasonably efficiently.  One way to do this is to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or a related sieve to find all the prime numbers less than 3 × 10<sup>6</sup>, then use a DP algorithm: mark 1 has having just itself as a prime factorization, and then for each number 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 3 × 10<sup>6</sup>, try dividing those numbers by the primes, in sequence, until you find one that divides cleanly, leaving a remainder of r.  The prime factorization of that number will then be the prime factorization of r, times the prime number you divided out.

Once you have the prime factorization of all of these numbers, you can efficiently compute the prime factorization of n! using the prime factorization of the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., n.  To do this, you can just add up all of the exponents of the corresponding primes in the factorization of the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., n.  You can similarly compute a prime factorization for q!, and then get a prime factorization for (q!)<sup>r</sup> by multiplying all the exponents in the prime factorization of q! by r.

Once you have these prime factorizations, you can then compute n! / (q!)<sup>r</sup> by simply doing a pairwise subtraction of all of the exponents in the prime factorization of n! by the corresponding exponents in the prime factorization of (q!)<sup>r</sup>.  You can then recover the value of n! / (q!)<sup>r</sup> by multiplying all of these numbers together.

If you need an exact value, then you will probably spend more work multiplying all of the factors together than actually finding those factors.  If you only need the value modulo some large prime, then this method will be very efficient and will give you an exact answer, as long as you mod by that large prime as you multiply all the factors together.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @VidyutVyom- You should be able to code this up yourself.  See my comment on your question.

Comment: There's a much, much easier way.  See below.

Comment: @duffymo- I really like the math behind that approach.  But won't that lead to floating-point precision or rounding issues?

Comment: Which one?  Using gammln?  Both will be better than what you're proposing, in my opinion.

Comment: @duffymo- I was thinking about the one based on gammln - it's super elegant.  Is there a way to know how numerically stable it is?  (Also, I didn't realize that you had multiple solutions described - what was the other approach?)

Comment: I was referring to the prime factors above.  Numerically stable?  It's not iterative or recursive.  It's a function evaluation; see Numerical Recipes for details.  It'll be as stable as sine or cosine and as accurate as 64 bit IEEE will allow.

Comment: @duffymo- Ah, I misinterpreted what you said.  My concern is that since the OP might need an exact integer answer, finding the log of the value and exponentiating it might result in the wrong number due to a rounding error.  Is that not a concern here?

Comment: I would point out that it is certain this will overflow 64 bit precision for any large value of n as long as r is at least 2. So if you really do need an exact integer answer, then the gammaln solution will always fail.

Comment: For example, even this small case: factorial(1000)/factorial(500)^2 =  270288240945436569515614693625975275496152008446548287007392875106625428705522193898612483924502370165362606085021546104802209750050679917549894219699518475423665484263751733356162464079737887344364574161119497604571044985756287880514600994219426752366915856603136862602484428109296905863799821216320

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose another solution if you actually need the full result (not the result modulo some number) in a standard types, like a long. You could skip some calculation knowing that they are going to overflow.

1. First case:
   n is small, so q is small (so the hypothesis that it cleanly divides n!), calculation is easy,
   for example using @templatetypedef answer.
2. Second case
   n is big and q is small relatively to n: the result is Infinity.
   To determine whether or not q is small relatively to n, use the [Stirling Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). So if the result of:
   `exp((n*ln(n)-n)/(q*ln(q)-q)^r))` 
   is `Infinity` on double calculation, no need to actually compute the result. Especially when assuming you want the exact result in a long.
3. Third case:
   n is big and q is big as well. @templatetypedef applies as well.

Obviously, if you don't need the exact result, you could simply use the Stirling approximation when n and q are big enough. To be more precise, use [Ramanujan's version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152342/ramanujans-approximation-to-factorial).